# Variable URL with Instance Variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I know I'm being an idiot here, but I can't think of how this is done.  I am creating an app with certain interests and am using a a Wikipedia scrape set up using Nokogiri. I have two inputs: `Title` and `Wikipedia`, but want to fill `Summary` and `Content` in the data model using the scrape.  I want to use the `Wikipedia` attribute as a variable in a url within a method, but keep getting the error `dynamic constant assignment PAGE_URL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/i...`.

I thought that the methods should go in the model, with reference to them in the Create definition under the controller, but this doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT**

I've just tried taking the constants out of the methods as suggested, but I am still getting a dynamic constant assignment error.  My model currently looks like this:

```
PAGE_URL1 = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title="
PAGE_URL2 = "&printable=yes"

def get_PAGE_URL
    PAGE_URL = PAGE_URL1 + self.wikipedia + PAGE_URL2
end


def get_page
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))
end

def get_summary
    get_PAGE_URL
    self.summary = page.css("p")[0].text
end

def get_full_page
    get_PAGE_URL
    puts page.css('div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr p').each do |p|
        self.content = puts p.text
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants can't go inside of methods, they must be defined inside of the class' direct scope.

Edit:

For example:

```
class WikiScraper
    PAGE_URL = "http://www.wikipedia.org/"

    def scrape
      page_num = '5'
      my_url = PAGE_URL + page_num
    end

 end
```

Comment: You still have a dynamic assignment on the line `PAGE_URL = PAGE_URL1 + self.wikipedia + PAGE_URL2`. Any all capitalized variable will be treated as a constant. To solve this change `PAGE_URL` to `page_url`